# Jenkins Test Result Trend graph/chart for aggregated downstream test results?

Tags: jenkins

Is it possible to display "Test Result Trend" graph/chart for aggregated downstream test results ?

I enabled the post build action "Aggregate downstream test results" and I can see "Aggregated Test Result" in the left navigation. Then, I can click on left navigation and drill down to individual downstream jobs with graphs plotted. But is it possible to see a single graph which includes results of all downstream tests ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that 'Aggregated Test Results' feature is buggy. [See this](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-9920), for example. When I tried it in Jenkins 1.437 the upstream job displayed the graph with 0 tests and showed *No Tests* under *Latest Test Results*, although it did display tests per build.